# How to access the command line arguments (./program arg1 arg2 arg3)

Tags: assembly, arm, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

How could I access to those arguments? I have read that they are stored in r1, but I am not able to access them.

For example, in this code:

```
.global main

main:
        ldr     r2, [r1, #4]
        ldr     r0, [r2]
        bx      lr
```

If I execute the program with 7 value:

```
./program 7
echo $?
```

I got 55, that is the decimal ASCII representation of 7.

So I tried to add SUB line:

```
.global main

main:
        ldr     r2, [r1, #4]
        sub     r2,r2,#48        // to actually obtain 7
        ldr     r0, [r2]
        bx      lr
```

But I got 0. Why?

**EDIT (it works):**

```
.global main

main:
        ldr     r2, [r1,#4]
        ldr     r0, [r2]
        sub     r0, r0, #48
        bx      lr
```

But what I have not clear is, why doesn't it work if I use r0 instead of r2? Like this:

```
.global main

main:
        ldr     r0, [r1,#4]
        sub     r0, r0, #48
        bx      lr
```

Comment: have you tried simply printing the input value to confirm you are using the input value?   where did you convert the number from ascii?

Comment: are you building this for arm or thumb?  where are you running this?  whole lot of information missing in this question.

Comment: for arm. I am running this on raspberry pi.

Comment: where did you take the string pointer and then find the 7 and then convert that to ascii is what I should have said.

Comment: are you building for 32 bit or 64 bit?  you able to run 32 bit on your raspberry pi is it a 64 bit linux?

Comment: mov pc,lr is a bad choice either way on top of the othe rissues

Comment: why `mov pc,lr` is a bad choice? also the raspberry pi is 64 bit but I am compiling with the 32 bit gcc toolchain.

Comment: If you think it is fine then why are you onconsistent, why use bx lr in one place and mov pc, lr in another?  Why even us bx lr in main when you can pop to the pc?

Comment: @Mnkisd: also note that address in `r1` will point to the executable name. Check it in gdb: `x/s *($r1)` -> `0x7efffd83:     "/home/pi/a.out"`

Comment: start by using printf to find the "7" then convert that into a 7 and then sort out any factorial issues.

Comment: think about int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) or **argv or argv[][] whichever makes the most sense to you and then figure out where the string "7" fits into that and then what r1 represents.  In C would you be doing printf("%d",argv); ?   try it see what the compiler tells you.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk you are right! but I don't know how to access it

Comment: even if you were to printf("%d",argv[1][0]); what would you see?  a 7?  nope.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk r1 points to an array of addresses it does not point to the executable name it points to the address where the executable name lives.  the second address in that list is argv[1] and so on.  [r1,#0],  [r1,#4], etc.

Comment: what happens when you simply pass a 7 to the factorial function and dont mess with the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    printf("%d\n",argv);
    return(0);
}
so.c: In function ‘main’:
so.c:5:12: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
```

that is your first problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    printf("%d\n",argv[1][0]);
    return(0);
}
./so 7
55
```

55 = 0x37

If you had gotten past that this would be your second problem

Could solve the first by simply asking the compiler to show you a path.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    return(argv[1][0]);
}

   0:   e5913004    ldr r3, [r1, #4]
   4:   e5d30000    ldrb    r0, [r3]
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Think about how the C function is called and then translate that to assembly. An array of pointers to strings.

And then depending on the instruction set you may have additional issues in the factorial function.

EDIT:

```
.global main

main:
        ldr     r2, [r1, #4]   <--- address of the pointer to the string
        sub     r2,r2,#48  <---- hoses the pointer to the string
        ldr     r0, [r2] <---- who knows what this is reading
        bx      lr
```

Look at the code the compiler generated (assuming 7 is the first parameter on the command line ./so 7)

```
   0:   e5913004    ldr r3, [r1, #4] <---- pointer to string (param 1)
   4:   e5d30000    ldrb    r0, [r3] <---- get first byte in string
                             r0 now contains 0x37
                    ldrb    r0, [r3,#1] <----- If I added this line
                             r0 now contains 0x00 string termination
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Now think about Frant's answer, how you convert a string to a number if the string is some number in some base ("7", "0x123", "68", etc).

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me! I updated the thread with an updated version with the help of your comment. But still I can't succeed.

Comment: I appreciate greatly that you are interacting by editing your question, but replacing the code makes our answers and comments out of sync and not make sense.  So perhaps add edits sequentially rather than replace the question.  I could go back and re-write my answer each time I guess.  But we cant fix comments, and not everyone is going to keep re-writing their answers, we dont get notifications to indicate the question has been edited to know we need to come back to this question.

Comment: Really thanks you for help. I don't get why I have to use ldrb instead of ldr, since it works even with ldr. Also, I edited the post because there is one last thing that I have not clear, if you could help me :)

Comment: if you used ldr you would get four bytes from the string ldrb gets one byte from the string.  maybe you were lucky and the string with 0x37, 0x00 and two other bytes were zeros after that.  also if it wasnt aligned then you might get a fault, being a string it doesnt have to be aligned

Comment: you should be treating it as a string of one OR MORE characters and properly converting it from ASCII to a number before using it (see Frant's answer).

Comment: thanks. Even though there's this last thing that I don't have clear in the thread (I updated it)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the string "7" as an argument, not the value 7, you have to convert it into a binary value.

Remember, the signature for the main function is `int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)`.

That is, the number of argument will be in r0, the pointer to the array of the parameters strings will be in r1, and the pointer to the array of environment zero-terminated strings will be in r2.

In order to retrieve "7", you need to access argv[1](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eprabal/teaching/resources/eecs373/ARM-AAPCS-EABI-v2.08.pdf)  - argv[0] will  be the zero-terminated string containing path to the program you are executing.

If you are passing 1 to 9, you can just substract '0' or 0x30 in order to the value retrieved in argv[1](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eprabal/teaching/resources/eecs373/ARM-AAPCS-EABI-v2.08.pdf).

For other values than '1'.. '9', you should call atoi() from your assembly program, or convert it by yourself for the fun.

[Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eprabal/teaching/resources/eecs373/ARM-AAPCS-EABI-v2.08.pdf) is a good read for understanding how to call C functions form assembly or vice versa.

Comment: I edited the post, the thing is that I always got different values, so there must be something wrong.

Comment: @Mnkisd: `r1` holds `char **argv`, which is a pointer to an array of pointers to char, like @Arkadiusz Drabczyk pointed out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798713/how-to-access-the-command-line-arguments-program-arg1-arg2-arg3#comment112817135_63798713) a couple minutes earlier.   It's randomized by stack ASLR, and the exit status `$?` is the low 8 bits of it.

Comment: I updated the post with a new updated version, I do progessess but still can't succeed.

Comment: @Mnkisd: see old_timer's lastest edit - you should be close.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Frant , even though I don't understand one thing (I updated the thread with this thing that I don't have clear).